# Post-receive, request php script, pull git repo

Tags: php, git, curl, git-post-receive

I have a PHP script git.php on my web-server with only a few lines, one of the lines uses shell_exec() to run a

```
'git pull ssh://user@X.com/repo.git'
```

*(Please note, you cannot push to the webserver, this is disabled and cannot be enabled. )*
This all works fine if you go to example.com/git.php. The script runs and the repo gets updated. (the repo is on another unrelated server)

What I am trying to do is use my post-receive hook to update my git repo on my web server from my git server. I am using ssh to connect, so hooks should (and do work, i have tested that) work, and am pretty sure there are no permissions problems.

My question is how do I write the 'post-receive' script?

I have tried a few things with no luck, my script is currently 1 line long and looks something like this

```
curl -d "action=post-receive&log=1" http://example.com/git.php
```

but this does nothing. :(

Is there anyone who can help me? Or suggest anything that I could do better?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well first of all post you full `git.php` script (minus credentials if any). Otherwise it's not clear how it would behave if calling would be successfull. Additionally how do you debug? What about writing a log each time your script is called so you can actually see how the request looks like (or if there isn't any)?!

Comment: I was just starting off with something small, quite new to git, i've not got any sort of logging. my git.php >> `if( ($action == "post-receive")){echo "<h2>Git 'post-receive' Running</h2>;  shell_exec('git pull '. $git_remote);}`

Comment: execute the curl command from your shell and take a look what happens. Also do some error output in case no `$action` has been specified. Otherwise you're flying blindly.

Comment: Where is '$git_remote' coming from? For goodness sake don't run POSTed values on the shell. That would be a massive security hole.